# CopyOnWriteArrayList or Vector

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

All,

The edge **Vector** class has over **ArrayList** is that it is synchronized and hence ensures thread-safety. However, between CopyOnWriteArrayList and Vector, what should be the preferred considering thread safety and performance in consideration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Overall, it depends on the frequency and nature of read and write operations, and the size of the array.

You'll need to benchmark in your context to be sure, but here are some general principles:

- If you are **only going to read the
  array**, then even ArrayList is
  thread safe (since the only
  non-thread-safe modifications are
  those that modify the list). Hence
  you would want to use a
  non-synchronised data structure,
  either ArrayList or
  CopyOnWriteArrayList would probably
  work equally well.
- If **reads are much more common
  compared to writes** then you would
  tend to prefer CopyOnWriteArrayList,
  since the array copying overhead is
  only incurred on writes.
- If the **size of the Array is
  small**, then the cost of making
  array copies will also be small,
  hence this will favour
  CopyOnWriteArrayList over Vector.

You may also want to consider two other options:

- Use an ArrayList but put the **synchronisation elsewhere** to ensure thread safety. This is actually the method I personally use most often - basically the idea is to use a separate, higher-level lock to protect all the relevant data structures at the same time. This is much more efficient than having synchronisation on every single operation as Vector does.
- Consider an immutable [**persistent data structure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) - these are guaranteed to be thread safe due to immutability, do not require synchronisation and also benefit from low overhead (i.e. they share most data between different instances rather than making complete new copies). Languages like [Clojure](http://clojure.org/data_structures) use these to get ArrayList-like performance while also guaranteeing full thread safety.

Comment: Also, consider using Collections.synchronizedList to wrap a non-thread-safe List, instead of doing external synchronizations

Comment: "use a separate, higher-level lock... This is much more **efficient** than having synchronisation on every single operation" --> Convenient may be, but efficient? I would think a higher level lock is exactly the opposite of efficient.

Comment: "use a separate, higher-level lock... This is much more **efficient** than having synchronisation on every single operation" --> Convenient may be, but efficient? I would think a higher level lock is exactly the opposite of efficient.

Comment: It is almost always more efficient - you only need to enter/exit the lock once (at the top level) rather than potentially thousands or millions of times as you access each element.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on the usage pattern - if you have much more reads than writes, use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, otherwise use `Vector`.

`Vector` introduces a small synchronization delay for each operation, when `CopyOnWriteArrayList` has a longer delay for write (due to copying) but no delay for reads.

Another consideration is a behaviour of iterators - `Vector` requires explicit synchronization when you are iterating it (so write operations can't be executed at the same time), `CopyOnWriteArrayList` doesn't.

Comment: Sounds Intresting